# L'origine de « guili-guili »

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, interjections

D'où vient l'expression *guili-guili* ? Le mots *chatouiller*, *chatouille*, *chatouillement* sont-ils courants ? Quand les enfants apprennent-ils ces mots-ci ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attention : Dans ce qui va suivre, je n'affirme rien. Les ouvrages de référence restant muets à ce sujet, je ne fais que livrer la conjecture la plus plausible.

On commencera par noter que l'allemand dit un truc assez similaire : *killekille* le basque *kilikili* et il me semble que même l'indonésien dit un truc semblable.
Ceci additionné à la corrélation de sonorité k-g, au moins en germain.
Il faut donc aller chercher loin dans le temps de nos racines indo-européennes.

Dans ce sens, par analogie avec *guilleret*, *guili* pourrait être dérivé de l'ancien français *guiler* (tromper), lui même remontant au francique *wigila* (ruse) à rapprocher du haut-allemand *gilen* (se moquer) et de l'allemand *geil*

Comment: Et pour répondre à la seconde question dans la question, chatouille, chatouiller et chatouillement sont assez courants oui, la plupart des enfants en bas âge les connaissent

Comment: et tout simplement parce que c'est relativement facile pour les enfants de bas âge de prononcer cette expression, plutôt que *chatouiller* avec sa dernière syllabe assez compliquée